# Why does this for loop cycle through elements not specified?

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, ionic-framework, for-of-loop

I'm creating a checklist with items and subitems. I have a button to reset all checkboxes and I need to check if the items are all checked, but NOT the subitems.

But my checking code logs ALL the checklist boxes, not just the items.

Here is the template:

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor='let listitem of checkdetail.contents; let i=index'>
        <ion-label class="mainitem" *ngIf="listitem.flavour === 'item'" text-wrap>{{listitem.content}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox color="primary" checked="false" *ngIf="listitem.flavour === 'item'" [(ngModel)]="item_ticks[i]" (ionChange)="updateTicks()"></ion-checkbox>

        <ion-label class="subitem" *ngIf="listitem.flavour === 'subitem'" text-wrap>{{listitem.content}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox color="secondary" checked="false" *ngIf="listitem.flavour === 'subitem'" [(ngModel)]="subitem_ticks[i]" ></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

And here is the code:

```
item_ticks = [];
    subitem_ticks = [];

    updateTicks() {
        for(var item of this.item_ticks){
            console.log(item);
        }
    }

    resetTicks() {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Reset?',
            message: 'Are you sure?',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                  console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
              },
              {
                text: 'Reset',
                handler: () => {
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.item_ticks.length; i++){
                        this.item_ticks[i] = false;
                    }   
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.subitem_ticks.length; i++){
                        this.subitem_ticks[i] = false;
                    }
                    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                      message: 'Checklist reset',
                      duration: 1000,
                      position: 'top'
                    });
                    toast.present();
                }
              }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
    }
```

Why does the loop in updateTicks() log out both the this.item_ticks AND this.subitem_ticks?

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in a plunker, because based on this code, it worked fine for me :)

Comment: It looks right, doesn't it? I'll stick it in plunker later

Comment: Yes it looks right and seemed to worked right as well, so I wonder if there is something going on elsewhere in the code :)

Comment: There must be... I'll investigate. That for loop looks fine to me. What did you test it in?

Comment: Of course I couldn't test the whole reset function, but the iteration and setting to false. In this demo I added a couple of console logs to keep track of when iteration starts and when ends, to better keep track: http://plnkr.co/edit/pyeiqVh5409ZX7kdZ0kL?p=preview

Comment: Great stuff. So your code looks like mine. With one big difference - you don't have an item after your subitem. Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/wpYaoiigcJmcdXL6dG6f You'll see the console logs get an undefined if you tick that last box - that's issue!

Comment: Ah, I see... didn't think of trying that... :) Well, actually it's not including the subitem, BUT the issue is, that you are showing both subitems and items in same iteration, and that subitem "steals" one index from there, so when you are iterating it tries in this case to print the index 2 (where the subitem is) it will of course be undefined, since there is no item with such index in the `item_ticks` array. You can see it well here, where I print the complete `item_ticks` array: http://plnkr.co/edit/UYyYBVA0SzDOYxgfXhAC?p=preview

Comment: You should use something else than the index to push into the array, maybe an `id`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147557/discussion-between-subjective-effect-and-ajt-82).